# Changing line properties in Matlab plots

Tags: matlab, plot

I have been trying to make line properties in Matlab change when invoked inside a for loop. The automatic systems such `ColorOrder` and `LineStyleOrder` have proven to be useless as they will not both index at once. I need to change both the color and the marker/line style for each line. The best solution I have found it this:

```
hold on;
col = hsv(5);
mar = ['d','o','s','^','v','<','>'];
beta = [1,2,3,4,5];

for m = 1:length(beta)
    b = beta(m);
    y=[];
    s = 0:05:8;
    for m = s
        y = [y integral(@(f)fun(m,b,f),0.0001,1000)];
    end
    plot(s,y./y(1),'Marker',mar(m),'color',col(m,:),'DisplayName',num2str(b))
    legend('-DynamicLegend'); %automatically generate legend
end
hold off;
```

Where I have been forced to loop over the length of beta instead of beta itself in order to have an iterator for the color and marker. However, despite this being exactly as described in the documentation, neither the color nor the marker are changing. I suspect there is some strange interaction going on, but I cannot figure out what it is. Does anyone know why this is not resulting in different color and markers for different lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I read somewhere that in earlier versions of Matlab we could not change both properties at the same time during the call to `plot`...I wish I had the reference. I'm using R2013a and it does not work anyhow.

As a workaround, you can assign a handle to individual plots and change both properties at the same time *after* the plot is done.

In other words, use something like:

```
hPlot = plot(...)
set(hPlot,'Marker',...,'Color',...,'LineStyle',...)
```

With your code, that would look like this:

```
clear
clc
close all

hold on;
col = hsv(5);
mar = {'d','o','s','^','v'};
%// ======== NEW ========\\%
linestyles = {'-' '--' ':' '-.' '-'}
beta = [1,2,3,4,5];

%// Dummy function
fun = @(x,y,z) x.*y-z;

for m = 1:length(beta)
    b = beta(m);
    y=[];
    s = 0:05:8;
    for m = s
        y = [y integral(@(f)fun(m,b,f),0.0001,1000)];
    end
    %// ======== NEW ========\\%
    hPlot(b) = plot(s,y./y(1));

    set(hPlot(b),'Marker',mar{b},'color',col(b,:),'LineStyle',linestyles{b},'DisplayName',num2str(b))

    legend('-DynamicLegend'); %automatically generate legend
end
hold off;
```

With the following output:

[image]